# How to resolve "please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property"?

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I tried all the possible solutions posted by other people but still I am struggling to resolve this issue. I believe in my case, it has got to do something with the `agents`. I will post 2 codes, the one code works but the other doesn't. Both the codes call the same `groovy` methods but still the second code snippet doesn't work.

The below `code 1` works fine and executed the pipeline successfully:

```
pipeline{
        agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }

        stages{
            stage('Checkout') {
                steps{
                    checkout scm
                }
            }

            //Build and Unit Tests
            stage('Build and Unit Tests') {
                steps{
                    script{
                        if (buildType.buildSystem == 'npm'){
                            buildNpm(configuration)
                        } else {
                            build(configuration)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // SonarQube Analysis
            stage('SonarQube analysis') {
                steps{
                    script{
                        if (buildType.buildSystem != 'npm'){
                            sonarQubeGating(configuration)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory
            stage('Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory') {
                steps{
                    artifactoryImagePush(configuration)
                }
            }

            // Approve DEV Deployment
            stage('Approve Dev Deployment') {
                agent none
                when {
                    anyOf {
                        expression {
                            return (env.GIT_BRANCH.equals('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-'))
                        }
                    }
                }
                steps{
                    approveDeployment()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The below `code 2` doesn't work:

```
pipeline{
        agent none

        stages{
            stage('Checkout') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                steps{
                    checkout scm
                }
            }

            //Build and Unit Tests
            stage('Build and Unit Tests') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                steps{
                    script{
                        if (buildType.buildSystem == 'npm'){
                            buildNpm(configuration)
                        } else {
                            build(configuration)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // SonarQube Analysis
            stage('SonarQube analysis') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                steps{
                    script{
                        if (buildType.buildSystem != 'npm'){
                            sonarQubeGating(configuration)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory
            stage('Build Docker Image and Push to Artifactory') {
                agent { label 'docker-kitchensink-slave' }
                steps{
                    unstash 'artifacts'
                    unstash 'artifacts'
                    artifactoryImagePush(configuration)
                }
            }

            // Approve DEV Deployment
            stage('Approve Dev Deployment') {
                agent none
                when {
                    anyOf {
                        expression {
                            return (env.GIT_BRANCH.equals('master') || env.GIT_BRANCH.startsWith('hotfix-'))
                        }
                    }
                }
                steps{
                    approveDeployment()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error as below:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.6.0.1398:sonar (default-cli) on project xyz-service: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property. -> [Help 1]

Below is my `sonar` code:

```
void call(Map optionParams = [:]) {
    script {
        try {
            String jacocoPath = optionParams.get('buildSystem').equals('gradle') ?
                    'build/JacocoReport/test/jacocoTestReport.xml' : 'target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml'

            glSonarMavenScan gitUserCredentialsId: 'sonar-key', javaVersionForSonar: '11.0', mavenVersion: '3.5.4',
                    additionalProps: ['sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' : jacocoPath]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            echo "The following Sonar exception thrown ${e}"
            //Stop build here, unless 'requireSonar' is set to False (String or Boolean)
            if (!optionParams.get('requireSonar').toString().equalsIgnoreCase('false')) {
                throw e
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what you're trying to achieve here.  You are showing the code that works. Are you trying to understand WHY the first block works, compared to the second, or are you just trying to get it working?  If the latter, clearly you are already done.

If the former, I'm only familiar with scripted pipeline, not declarative pipeline, but it seems possible to me that if there is more than one build node that satisfies that label, then each of those "agent" lines could potentially select a build node, and each one could potentially select a different one.  If the build step executes a different node than the sonarqube scan is run on, you will find yourself in a workspace without any compiled classes.

Comment: The issue with the `code 1`(although it works fine) is that, my jobs are holding onto the agent while waiting for the input as it makes those nodes unavailable to other users while, at the same time, they’re sitting idle and waiting. In 'code 1', in approve deployment stage, even after specifying 'agent none', it's holding onto the agent which is not the best practice.  
So, is it possible to call a scripted pipeline from declarative?

Comment: I doubt that's going to help you. No matter what, the SonarQube scan will have to run on the same agent that ran the compile step. In any case, I doubt you can combine "declarative" and "scripted" in any way. You have to make a choice, but again, I doubt that will solve the problem you think you have.